# Fill arrow head goes off in line in canvas Android

Tags: android, canvas, paint

The `arrow head` with `stroke` working fine in canvas, but the `filled arrow head` is not drawing at the right position ,Here is my code for draw arrow.

```
 private void drawArrow(Point startPoint, Point endPoint, Paint paint, Canvas mCanvas) {
        Path mPath = new Path();
        float deltaX = endPoint.x - startPoint.x;
        float deltaY = endPoint.y - startPoint.y;
        //float frac = (float) 0.1;
        int ARROWHEAD_LENGTH = 15;
        float sideZ = (float) Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
        float frac = ARROWHEAD_LENGTH < sideZ ? ARROWHEAD_LENGTH / sideZ : 1.0f;
        float point_x_1 = startPoint.x + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX + frac * deltaY);
        float point_y_1 = startPoint.y + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY - frac * deltaX);
        float point_x_2 = endPoint.x;
        float point_y_2 = endPoint.y;
        float point_x_3 = startPoint.x + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaX - frac * deltaY);
        float point_y_3 = startPoint.y + (float) ((1 - frac) * deltaY + frac * deltaX);
        mPath.moveTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
        mPath.lineTo(point_x_2, point_y_2);
        mPath.lineTo(point_x_3, point_y_3);
        //mPath.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
        //mPath.lineTo(point_x_1, point_y_1);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);
        invalidate();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this issue, I have placed the end line to the center of triangle.

You can do it with this formula :

```
float endLineX = (point_x_1 + point_x_2 + point_x_3) / 3;
float endLineY = (point_y_1 + point_y_2 + point_y_3) / 3;
```

Voilà

Comment: Can you please explain more about it?